# What is "kao se" in Taiwanese for "挖苦"?

Tags: meaning

Heard `"kao se"` on Taiwanese TV where the subtitles read: `"挖苦"`.

It's probably a Hokkien word but what can it be?

I'm not finding anything when searching

"kao se" and "挖苦" in Baidu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[剾洗](https://www.moedict.tw/%27%E5%89%BE%E6%B4%97)**

> 剾洗
>
> khau‑sé
>
> 又
>
> khau‑sué
>
> ㄎㄠ　ㄙㄨㆤˋ
>
> 動
>
> 諷刺、挖苦人家。
>
> 伊誠共人剾洗。
>
> ㄧㄐㄧㆩˊㆣㄠˊㄍㄚ˫ㄌㄤˊㄎㄠㄙㆤˋ
>
> 他很會諷刺人家。

The proper spelling would be `khau‑sé` and not `kao se` unfortunately.